# Update PHP-SQL statement not working - no errors shown

Tags: php, sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the following code...

```
$interactionid = '123';
$interactioncode = "ECWL";
$oldDOL = $_GET['oldDOL'];

$newDOL = $_GET['newDOL'];


    include("ORCLconfig.php");
    $addWSclaim = oci_parse($conn, "UPDATE claims SET DATE_OF_LOSS='$newDOL' WHERE NUMBER='32122'");
                  oci_execute($addWSclaim, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);


    $addtointeractionMAKE = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO interaction_items VALUES (null, '$interactionid', '$interactioncode', '$oldDOL', '$newDOL', localtimestamp)");
                            oci_execute($addtointeractionMAKE, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
```

oldDOL and newDOL are dates which arrive in the format DD-MMM-YY which is inline with the DATE_OF_LOSS column in the claims table.

However only the second statement seems to be working as there is no change on the claims table nor are there any errors shown.

I'm using an Oracle database and if I do the update statement in the SQL console it works fine.

Knowing me it will be something remarkably simple which i've somehow overlooked but any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: 1) SQL Injection 2) Your INSERT syntax is wrong (unless this is Oracle voodoo that you don't have to specify field names after the table)

Comment: firstly, I suggest you use oci_bind(_by_name) for your varialbes in the queries/inserts. Its clearer and safer than instring variables. The one oci_execute that is not working gives you a true or false back? if it is false what is in oci_error()?

Comment: @jampez77
What is value returned by first oci_execute? If it is false then check what is returned by oci_error.

Comment: @Leigh yes it is Oracle voodoo!

Comment: @onlineapplab.com there is no value returned bby the first oci_execute although i am not that familiar with oci_error as i am new to using oracle..........this is the code im trying to use to display any errors if (!$addWSclaim) {
     $e = oci_error($conn);  // For oci_parse errors pass the connection handle
     trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
    } but its not returning anything

Comment: @jampez77 you also need to get the return of oci_execute and see if it is false, not just the parse step. as others have also said, use bind variables, both for security and performance. also not specifying the field names in the insert, whist valid, is poor design (as if someone adds a new column with default, your code will break).

Comment: ok so i'm now using oci_bind_by_name and have updated my insert query to include the column name, still getting the same problem also how do i see if the first query comes back false?

Comment: @jampez77
oci_execute returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure so first check if there was an error on parse and then check again if there was an error on the execute.

Comment: @Leigh
It is not any voodoo it's pretty much standard SQL behaviour.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com I guess it's just my strict upbringing that has meant I've always specified a column list - I never knew it was acceptable to do it without.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com i'm sorry, not sure what you mean. how would i do that?

Comment: @Leigh
Omitting column names can be useful if you make INSERT...SELECT on tables with the same structure but I would agree with you that otherwise it is not a very good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $addWSclaim = oci_parse($conn, "UPDATE claims SET DATE_OF_LOSS='$newDOL' WHERE NUMBER='32122'");

 if ($addWSclaim) {
   if (oci_execute($addWSclaim, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS)) {
      if (oci_num_rows($addWSclaim) === 0) {
        /* No rows affected */
      }
   } else {

      /*Handle error through oci_error*/
   }
 } else {
   /* Handle parse error */
 }
```

[oci_execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: still nothing im afraid :/

Comment: @jampez77
You can check number of affected rows

Comment: @jampez77
Do you have any statements executed before this code? According to docs "A transaction begins when the first SQL statement that changes data is executed with oci_execute() using the OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT flag. Further data changes made by other statements become part of the same transaction. Data changes made in a transaction are temporary until the transaction is committed or rolled back. Other users of the database will not see the changes until they are committed."

Comment: Affected rows comes back with 0 every time and no these are the only two statements in my script

Comment: @jampez77
In such case I would check your WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement. Try making a SELECT to see if anything will be returned.

Comment: I've figured it out! I was sending the wrong number through the UPDATE statement! such an idiot sometimes. Since you have helped the most and given me some good advice about binding my variables ETC I shall accept your answer. so thank you :)